# Is there a way to display a loop all on one line in assembly?

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

So I am working on trying to get a loop to display something five times without going to a new line. Specifically, I want to display the word "Loop" 5 times on one line, "LoopLoopLoopLoopLoop." I am able to display them on separate lines easy enough, it seems like it automatically goes to a new line all by itself. I am quite new to assembly language so if anyone could explain what is going on here it would be a huge help.
Here is my code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
myMessageOne BYTE "Loop",0dh,0ah,0
.code
main PROC
    call Clrscr
    mov edx, OFFSET myMessageOne
    mov ecx, 5
myloopOne:
    call WriteString
    loop myloopOne
    call DumpRegs
    exit
```

It prints out this:

> Loop
>   Loop
>   Loop
>   Loop
>   Loop

But I need:

> LoopLoopLoopLoopLoop

I've tried using jmp in an attempt to move it back up to the line, but it doesn't work. I don't know too many other commands and all the things I've looked up to try and find a solution just seem to be people looking for help with new line, the exact opposite of what I need help with. Any tips and help are very much appreciated as I'd like to get a better understanding of what I need to do.

Also, I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express. It is my understanding that what program you are using matters more in assembly.

Comment: Remove the carriage return line feed in the string? Change `myMessageOne BYTE "Loop",0dh,0ah,0` to `myMessageOne BYTE "Loop",0`

Comment: Check ASCII table for non-printable characters.. and also you may want to check disassembly of the code to see how that `BYTE "Loop"` compiles into memory values and how that relates to ASCII table. That would probably help you a lot to understand what is happening inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as the CR/LF is part of your string, it's displayed each time.
remove it, and make it another message:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
myMessageOne BYTE "Loop",0
str_crlf     BYTE 0dh,0ah,0

.code
main PROC
    call Clrscr

; write 5 "loop"s 
    mov edx, OFFSET myMessageOne     
    mov ecx, 5
myloopOne:
    call WriteString
    loop myloopOne

; and then the newline
    mov edx, OFFSET str_crlf
    call WriteString

    call DumpRegs
    exit
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm sorry it took me so long to respond. I posted this last night and then fell asleep and forgot to check it.

Comment: Actually, if it's possible and if you see this, can I ask you one more thing?

Comment: @ConorHastings sure you can, this is what SO is for (but why just me? ;) ) ... btw: "if you see this" : "ping" me (with @tommylee2k) and I get a notification that you wrote me

Comment: Thank you! I actually was finally able to go speak to my professor about everything. Thank you again for the help though!